# auto ajax call in ruby on rails is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to do this:
after my homepage loads (home.html.erb), call ajax to update the value of a tag on the same page.
Here is what I have in my home.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '<%= url_for(action: "home") %>'
    });
  });
</script>
```

and my home.js.erb

```
var id = 5;
$('#jquerylogo').html(id);
```

and my controller

```
def home
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # home.html.erb
    format.js
  end
end
```

but ajax is not called and the code doesn't work. why?
thanks.

Comment: Sorry but its unclear What are you trying to do? can you show a example? perhaps something on jsfiddle?

Comment: Inspect a console for any javascript errors.

Comment: I just want to use javascript to change the value of $('#jquerylogo'), but I want to do it with an ajax call that happens when the page loads... (this should be so simple but it's not working, if you want to know why I'm doing this it's because in the next step I want the code to do the ajax call every 10 sec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes ujs issues are tricksie.

I would start by adding a dataType to the ajax call to force the controller to respect it's type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    url: '<%= url_for(action: "home") %>'
  });
});
```

Things to look for are:

- Check the javascript console to see what (if any) errors you have
- Check your log to see if the request is made/received/rendered as html

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSS, it worked. Thanks a lot, you made my day (I wasted a few hours trying to fix this). I'm not familiar with javascript console. Can you point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console - Chrome   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript - Firefox   https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html - Safari -- But for usage this site has good tips: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139949/debugging-javascript-with-firebug/